# NSComparisonResult, how can I compare a searchText to multiple strings?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, search, comparison, tableview

I'm using this code for searching in my tableview:

```
for (Actor *actorz in arr)
{     
     NSComparisonResult result = [actorz.actorNaam compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:[actorz.actorNaam rangeOfString:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)]];
     if (result == NSOrderedSame)
     {
          [self.filteredListContent addObject:actorz];
     }   
}
```

Now I'm wondering how it'd be possible to not only compare the searchText to actorz.actorNaam but also to actorz.actorBeschrijving ? So I want to compare the searchText to two strings..

Comment: This method is just searching for the searchText into the names of the Actors... if it's found, it's added into the filteredListContent array... But I don't want to only search in to the names (actorz.actorNaam) but in the actorz.actorBeschrijving too..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The search methods of `NSString` return an `NSRange` with the location set to `NSNotFound` if the string has not been found.

Hence you can check if the string has been found by verifying that the results location is *not* `NSNotFound`. It may sound a bit backwards but the logic is solid (two negations, so to speak).

```
NSRange nameResult  = [actorz.actorNaam rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch];
NSRange descrResult = [actorz.actorBeschrijving rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch];

if ( nameResult.location != NSNotFound || descrResult.location != NSNotFound ) {
    [self.filteredListContent addObject:actorz];
}
```

Notice that this snippet will find names that contain the search string, not only names are equal. You may want to change that using your original code. You would of course have to drop the nameResult, as it would be superfluous:

```
NSComparisonResult result = [actorz.actorNaam compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:[actorz.actorNaam rangeOfString:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)]];
NSRange descrResult = [actorz.actorBeschrijving rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch];
    
if ( result == NSOrderedSame || descrResult.location != NSNotFound ) {
    [self.filteredListContent addObject:actorz];
}
```

However, there is a simpler way. Consider using predicates:

```
NSPredicate *actorPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"actorNaam contains[cd] %@ OR actorBeschrijving contains[cd] %@", searchText, searchText];

self.filteredListContent = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:actorPred];
```

Comment: How do I use the 2 NSRanges, nameResult en descrResult in combination with my old code?

Comment: Thanks.
I can search on the actorz.actorBeschrijving, but the search is delivering results I did not search for.

Comment: thanks for the help though :) however, can you explain me this a little bit more: `if ( result == NSOrderedSame || descrResult.location != NSNotFound )`

Comment: That is a standard C-style if-statement. The use of `NSNotFound` is explained in the beginning of my answer. Is there anything specific in that construct that you have doubts about?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure why you want to do a comparison, it seems to make more sense to me to check for existence of the search text within the strings you're searching. If that approach works for you you could give this a try:

```
NSArray *toCompareTo = @[actorz.actorNaam, actorz.actorBeschrijving];
[toCompareTo enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *object, NSUinteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([object rangeOfString:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)].location != NSNotFound) {
        [self.filteredListContent addObject:object];
        *stop = YES;
    }}];
```

Comment: `for (Actor *actorz in arr)
         
        {
        toCompareTo = @[actorz.actorNaam, actorz.actorBeschrijving];
        [toCompareTo enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *object, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            if ([object rangeOfString:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)].location != NSNotFound) {
                [self.filteredListContent addObject:object];
                *stop = YES;
            }}];
            
        }`
gives me this error:
[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]

Comment: So one of your fields is `nil`, probably `actorz.actorBeschrijving`. Create the array differently then, build it element by element with `addObject:` and check for `nil` always.