# Objective-C If Or statement

Tags: objective-c, c, if-statement

Is there any way to use an `if` statement like this?

```
if ([number isEqualToString:@"1" 'or' @"2" 'or' @"3")] {
```

Is this 'or' possible and how would I do this?

Comment: Read some basic of Objective C.

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893765/nscomparisonresult-how-can-i-compare-a-searchtext-to-multiple-strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if ([number isEqualToString:@"1"] || [number isEqualToString:@"2"] || [number isEqualToString:@"3"])` or if you have an NSArray of your string objects you can just check `[NSArray containsObject:]` to find if string actually contains in array.

Answer (score 2):

Not like that but you can create simple method to compare string to strings in array.

```
- (BOOL)arrayContainsEqualString:(NSString *)string array:(NSArray *)array {
    for(NSString *str in array) {
        if([str isEqualToString:string]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

And calling that method

```
if([self arrayContainsEqualString:@"stringToCompare" array:@[@"str1", @"str2", @"str3"]]) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the variable `number` is of type string and you need to compare it with strings.

For this you can check it as:

```
NSString *number = @"2";

if ([@[@"1", @"2", @"3"] containsObject:number]) {
   NSLog(@"Contains");
}
else{
   NSLog(@"doesn't contain");
}
```